# How to preselect a <select> list item in Bootstrap using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, selecteditem

I have the following bootstrap markup and jQuery script and my select list item is not being pre-selected:

```
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="serviceType">Service Type</label>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="T">T</option>
          <option value="X">X</option>
        </select>
        <script>
          //$('[name=serviceType]').val( T ); // not working
          //$('#serviceType').val( T ); // not working
          //$('[name=serviceType]').val( "T" ); // not working
          $('#serviceType').val( "T" ); // not working
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with the jQuery? Thanks.

**Appended Note #1:**
My jQuery CDN lib link is right before the closing  tag whereas this container and javascript is up higher in the web doc. Does that matter?

**Appended Note #2:**
Added the jQuery CDN lib for complete view.

Comment: I have created a demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/9gjjj1tm/. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

$('select option[value="T"]').attr("selected",true);
});

Comment: does not work in my web doc @Francis. does this <script> container need to come after the jQuery lib in the document flow?

Comment: Hi H.Ferrence, your code is working properly I've tested it. import first the jquery lib before anything else.

Comment: "import first the jquery lib before anything else" -- meaning the jQuery CDN lib must be placed above my script in order for it to work? Placement  and order of the lib and my script matter?

Comment: Yep, once I move my script after the jquery lib it works. so placement and order matter.

Comment: Ok, learning something because I always thought `$(document).ready(function () {...});` meant I could position the the CDN lib at the bottom of the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this code on page load. You should be using **$( '#serviceType' ).val('T')**

Please check the code below

```
  <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="serviceType">Service Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <select id="serviceType" name="serviceType" class="form-control">
      <option value="S">S</option>
      <option value="T">T</option>
      <option value="X">X</option>
    </select>
    <script>
     $(function() {
      $( '#serviceType' ).val('T'); 
        });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dont forget to include jQuery file.

Comment: thanks @prashanth. I'll test it out. My jQuery is present but at the bottom of the document - after this section. Is that the reason?

Comment: does not work in my web doc @prashanth. does this <script> container need to come after the jQuery lib in the document flow?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#serviceType').val('T');
```

works